# how to grant update or select on some specified row in postgresql table?

Tags: postgresql, sql-grant

I want to create some roles in my Postgresql DB and grant some access.

I have student role and i want to grant this user type : can edit only record a bout him/her in student table and can not edit other rows

how can i do it?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a view on the table with an appropriate where clause, then grant access to that:

```
create view students_view as
select col1, col2, col3 -- limit column access here
from mytable
where <whatever>; -- limit row access here

-- limit what he can do here
grant update, select to student_role;
```

BTW It is a commonly held misconception that you can't update a view, but that is only true if the view is a join or similarly complicated query.

Comment: Until very recent Pg versions explicit triggers or rules were required to make views updatable, so it was kind-of true.

Comment: what about inserts? say your filter criteria is foo="bar". what happens if the users does an insert into students_view(foo) values ("bar"); or even, update students_view set foo="bar"; will they be able to do that? anyway to limit this type of behavior?

Comment: @chris to my mind, new/updated rows with foo=bar *should* be visible. If that is no good, either make the filter narrower, or use the id to filter on a specific whitelist of ids `...where id in (1,3,5,8,etc)`

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL doesn't have row-level declarative security (yet, there's ongoing work into it) so if you can't just create a view - say, if you have many different people who need this access - you will probably need a [`SECURITY DEFINER` helper function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY) or trigger.

You've got a couple of options:

- Write a `SECURITY DEFINER` function that lets them make only the permitted changes and limit their access to the table to `SELECT`, revoking `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT` rights; or
- write a trigger that tries to restrict them from making changes you don't want them to make and `GRANT` them write access to the table.

Of the two, the function and restricted rights approach is *by far* the safest option so long as you follow the `SECURITY DEFINER` secure coding guidelines set above - setting `search_path` for the function, avoiding dynamic SQL (`EXECUTE`) with string substitutions, etc.

The view approach given above can work quite nicely if it's a view that filters by `current_user`. You may also want to look at the new `SECURITY BARRIER` views; see [this post](http://rhaas.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/security-barrier-views.html) for a useful discussion of them.

Answer (score -1):

GRANT UPDATE(column) on tabela to user_name;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).